# How to prove the probability of 2 times expectation is less than 1/2?

Tags: probability, expectation, hash-function

Suppose X is a non-negative random variable and E(X) = m. Then how to prove the probability P[X ≥ 2m] ≤ 1/2, more generally P[X ≥ cm] ≤ 1/c, where c > 1?

Comment: The first part seems trivial since probabilities are *always* bounded by $1$.  Did you mean $1/2$?

Comment: This is called [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)

Comment: Yes, I mean 1/2, it's a typo, thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $P[X \geq cm] > 1/c \implies E(X) \geq cm*P[X \geq cm] > m$, since X is non-negative. This contradicts the assumption that $E(X) = m$, so it must be that $P[X \geq cm] \leq 1/c$.